# comparing a dataframe column with another data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame ({"skuid" :("45","22","32","33"), "country": ("A","B","C","A")})
df2 = pd.DataFrame ({"skuid" :("45","32","40","21"),"salesprice" :(10,0,0,30),"regularprice" : (9,10,0,2)})
```

I want to find how many rows does df2 have in common with df1 when country is A (only sum).

I want the output as 1, because skuid 45 is in both datasets and country is A.

I did by subsetting by country and using isin() like

```
df3 = df1.loc[df1['country']=='A']
df3['skuid'].isin(df2['skuid']).value_counts()
```

but I want to know whether I can do in single line.

Here what I tried to do in one line code

```
df1.loc['skuid'].isin(df2.skuid[df1.country.eq('A')].unique().sum()):,])
```

I know my mistake I'm comparing with df1 with df2 of a country that doesn't exist.
So, is there any way where I can do it in one or two lines, without subsetting each country

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df1.loc[df1['country']=='A', 'skuid'].isin(df2['skuid']).sum()
# out: 1
```

Or

```
(df1['skuid'].isin(df2['skuid']) & df1['country'].eq('A')).sum()
```

You can also do for all countries with `groupby()`:

```
df1['skuid'].isin(df2['skuid']).groupby(df1['country']).sum()
```

Output:

```
country
A    1
B    0
C    1
Name: skuid, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood you need this:

```
df3=df1[lambda x: (df1.skuid.isin(df2['skuid'])) & (x['country'] =='A') ].count()
```